# Task.Result causes potential deadlock

Tags: asp.net, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, c#-3.0

I have a piece of C# .Net code need to be debugged to check if it could cause threading related problems, and the suggestion I got was to replace the ContinueWith with await, which I agree with. However, I have doubts if the original code could cause problem, since someone also said it is fine to use Task.Result inside ContinueWith because the result is ready at that point. Hence, I am looking for more thoughts on if the code below could cause deadlock or threading related problems.

```
private Task<HttpResponseMessage> ProcessRequest(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
   
    //sendAsync is another asyc method in current class
    
     return base.sendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
                          .ContinueWith(task => 
                                          {
                                           return task.Result;
                                           }, cancellationToken) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use `await` instead of `ContinueWith`. I have a long blog post about [why `StartNew` (and `ContinueWith`) are problematic](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). The tl;dr version is that these methods are very low-level methods that have surprising behavior. They existed before async/await and are not designed to work well with those keywords.

Comment: I agree, but I am looking for advice on if the original  code could cause deadlock or threading related problems.

Comment: Yes, it can, because `ContinueWith` is not being used correctly.

Comment: Thank you Stephen. Could you please take a look at another question regarding Microsoft Azure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75393386/what-are-the-possible-reasons-trigger-picohelper-blocks-hundreds-of-threads